# Ayuda con: Wrong number of arguments or invalid propety assignment aca

Tags: vbscript

yo recien empiezo con el lenguaje de VBS y estoy haciendo cosas, aca estoy haciendo un generador de vbs que tengan msgbox con 2 respuestas, pero me da el error que aparece en el titulo con el SendKeys en la linea 17.

```
result=inputbox("Titulo")
Mensaje=inputbox("Pregunta del Msgbox")
rsp1=inputbox("Respuesta afirmativa")
rsp2=inputbox("Respuesta negativa")
vel=200
titulo=inputbox("Titulo del msgbox")

O = Chr(34)
C = Chr(40)
D = Chr(41)

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad.exe", 9

WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys "x=msgbox"" & O & "" & Mensaje & "" & O & ",4+64," & O & "" & titulo & "" & O & "

WScript.Sleep vel

WshShell.SendKeys "if x=7 then MsgBox"" & O & "" & rsp2 & "" & O & ",0+64," & O & "" & titulo & "" & O & "

WScript.Sleep vel

WshShell.SendKeys "if x=6 then MsgBox"" & O & "" & rsp1 & "" & O & ",0+64," & O & "" & titulo & "" & O & "

WScript.Sleep vel

WshShell.SendKeys "%{f4}"
WScript.Sleep vel

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep vel

WshShell.SendKeys "" & result & ".vbs"

WScript.Sleep vel

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

---

Para que lo puedan ver mejor: https://pastebin.com/DTbqXRgf

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, tu error principal esta en la concatenación, es normal confundirse entre lo que uno quiere escribir y lo que se escribe. Pasé a corregir las sentencias y a su vez quiero aclarar unos puntos:
Por ejemplo:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "x=msgbox{(}" & O & Mensaje & O & ",4 {+} 64," & O & titulo & O & "{)}"
```

Notarás las diferencias en el uso de comillas (") y concatenadores (&), pero en la sintaxis habia un error, la asignacion a una variable a partir de una sub rutina o funcion (en este caso la MsgBox) utiliza los parentesis como utilizaste correctamente en el ImputBox en las primeras lineas. En este caso lo debí poner entre corchetes los caracteres especiales (los parentesis "(", ")" y el "+") para que el `SendKeys` lo enviara.

El Resto quedaría asi:

```
WScript.Sleep vel
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep vel
WshShell.SendKeys "if x=7 then MsgBox" & O & rsp2 & O & ",0 {+} 64," & O & titulo & O
WScript.Sleep vel
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep vel
WshShell.SendKeys "if x=6 then MsgBox" & O & rsp1 & O & ",0 {+} 64," & O & titulo & O
```

PD: Seria mejor utilizar un Editor de texto como el Notepad++ o VbsEdit para ayudarte con la sintaxis y colorear lo que es string o es variable para no marearte al concatenar.